# Avoiding 2 '@' signs in email address when using \P{M} within regular expression

Tags: java, regex

I'm creating a validation regular expression for email addresses, the problem is that not only standard Latin chars are accepted but also Russian, Swedish and other languages that uses non Latin characters.

what i am using is the `\P{M}`
code, which basically allows the insertion of any Unicode codepoint.
The problem is..... i off course want only 1 '@' (at) allowed, as according to standard syntax for email addresses.
How can i avoid that?
This is the RegEx i have so far:

```
input.matches("\\P{M}+@{1}\\P{M}+\\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6}$");
```

Thx for any advice, i have been trying with a lot of different combinations but nothing so far

Thank you

Comment: It changes nothing, but you can use `\PM` without the braces for a single-letter property that’s one of the 7 general category groupings. Makes it a little easier to read because you don’t have to deal with the many things that braces already do.  I don’t understand why you would say `@{1}` instead of just `@`.

Answer (score 0):

```
(?:[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*|"(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21\x23-\x5b\x5d-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])*")@(?:(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?|\[(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?|[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]:(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21-\x5a\x53-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])+)\])
```

http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html

Comment: how about these? ß, ë, ñ, ç, æ, ü, ô, å, they are not handled in that regex

Comment: JBoy, they are not legal in e-mail addresses and for domain names there is Punycode.

Comment: Hi Joey, is there an official documentation about the allowed and non allowed chars? i could not find any...

Comment: The regex I posted is from "The Official Standard: RFC 2822".

Comment: http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6530  , this is more up to date, also note these examples, which are already accepted by some servers http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Internationalization_Examples